Get Multiple Instances of DbContext from IServiceProvider
I'm trying to simplify my DI scopes in an ASP.NET Core integration tests project. Currently I create three scopes, one for a read-only DbContext, one for a write-only DbContext, and one for everything else. I would really like to simplify this down to a single scope, but the issue is that I need two separate instances of DbContext so I can do independent read and write operations as part of the tests.
Is it possible to request different instances of a service using IServiceProvider when using GetRequiredServices<T>()?

You'll need to use IDbContextFactory to guarantee the creation of new instances when you're in a scoped context.

UPDATE: Hmm,IDbContextFactory is from EF6, not EFCore. But fortunately it's straightforward to redefine and reimplement it yourself for EFCore.

The service registration governs how the dependency, including DbContext, are returned. If registered as Scoped it is an instance per scope. If Transient then instance per dependency request. You can register multiple DbContexts, buy not really multiple instances of the same DbContext in the same scope without them being transient. (not ideal) Personally I use the DbContextScope (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zejji.DbContextScope.EFCore) which gives fine grained control of a scope for DbContext instances and supports read-only scopes.

Yes, its possible to get the request different instances of a service using IServiceProvider when using GetRequiredServices(). But you need register three different dbcontext inside the program.cs.

Perhaps keyed services - register with one key for readonly, one for read-write, maybe?

You'll need three contexts. Why not claims policies? Then you can use only one context.

I looked at the DbContextScope.EFCore library that Steve Py mentioned, but I didn't want to make too many changes, such as depending on another library, because I'm trying to keep the tests as close to testing a web application as it would be published as possible.
I also tried having multiple contexts by creating a ReadContext and WriteContext that inherited my original DbContext as Brando Zhang has suggested, but that went downhill fast because I was then forced to change my services to be generic and accept a TContext, unregister and register in the test setup, etc. It was getting me further away from my intent.
I settled on using the Keyed Services as suggested by Marc Gravell. I settled on a single scope, got all my services from it, and added just one "ReadContext" keyed service. Everything continued to work as it had before when I had three scopes, and I got my separate contexts as I wanted.
So, the solution was Keyed Services. Thank you all for the help!

Not the most idiomatic solution, but if you don't have a lot of services and you only want to use this for testing purposes - you could manually instantiate your DbContext along all it's services.
YourDbContext GetNewDbContext(IServiceScope scope)
{
  var serviceA = scope.GetRequiredService<IService>();
  var serviceB = ...;
  return new YourDbContext(serviceA, ...);
}

